# My Corsa makes a strange noise after 10mins of driving, any suggestions for the cause?

Tags: engine, noise, exhaust, vauxhall, corsa

So my 2007 Corsa Sxi 1.6L started making this noise after an audible 'Ping' happened while driving (at low speed, had just started my journey). It has been inspected by my local garage but they concluded that nothing is wrong with my exhaust. No cracks or splits in my exhaust, and nothing is loose.

The sound only occurs after 10 or so mins of driving and it is a noticeable change in the sound of the car.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated! Let me know any clarifying questions if needed :)

Link to the sound - https://youtube.com/shorts/noVPPzfoOuo?feature=share

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!